# Replace multiple `Match`es without `MatchEvaluator`'s restrictions

Tags: c#, regex, match

My application finds numbers in a date string for example `13/7/2019` or `7/13/2019`.

It replaces them with `mm` for the month and `dd` for the day.

If only one number is found (eg. `6 July 2019`), it should assume that it must be the day.

If not then the number that is `>12` will be the day and the other one will be the month.

It find the numbers using `Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d{1,2}")`

After looking through the matches, I have 2 variables (`Match? monthMatch, dayMatch`).

I then make a dictionary:

```cs
Dictionary<Match, string> matches = new();
if (monthMatch != null)
    matches.Add(monthMatch, "mm");
if (dayMatch != null)
    matches.Add(dayMath, "dd");
```

The question is how can I replace the `Dictionary<Match, string>` that I have.

Using the naive approach, the indexes in the string are changed after my first replacement and the second replacement fails miserably.

Eg. `7/13/2019` -> `dd/13/2019` -> `ddmm3/2019`

How can I do this in a way that will ensure the replacements are made based on their index in the original string not an intermediate replacement.

Comment: I have no idea what the motivation for closing this question was but it is not the same as the question it was marked as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to order them in descending order of index so that the indexes of the `Match` objects would still be valid after each substitution.

```cs
public static string SafeSubstitution (string input, Dictionary<Match, string> substitutions)
{
    foreach (var (match, replaceWith) in substitutions.OrderByDescending(s => s.Key.Index))
    {
        string subResult = match.Result(replaceWith);
        input = string.Concat(input.Substring(0, match.Index), subResult, input.Substr(match.Index + match.Length));
    }
    return input;
}
```